# Best practices for automated emails from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, wcf, email

I have been working on a Lightswitch 2012 (HTML 5) project two of it key requirements are report generation and triggered based emails to users.

Since lightswitch does not support reports and best way is to use ASP.NET, i used to generate reports, But now i am kind of stuck about how can i generate triggered based emails meaning like each night at 00:00 there should be some query run against database to generate emails to users, some options that i have are,

1) SQL jobs
2) WCF RIA Services
3) Console Based separate application

But client wont allow me any where near their servers so need a solution with minimal configuration on server but it must be reliable as well.
So please some advice in this regard is needed. Thanks!

Server is running Windows Server 2012 and they have there own mail server that i have to utilize.

Comment: I would make a console application, and create a task in the windows Task Scheduler that executes the console application every night at 00:00.

Comment: yes but there are always drunk admins who would not configure scheduler correctly and blame it all on my firm :)

Comment: Don't use scheduler. It doesn't work that well. Instead, build a Windows service application (you can have a separate switch to make it run as a service, but default to a console mode). Have that generate the emails.

Comment: By definition, if you need to _schedule_ something, it will need some _scheduler_. If you can express that to your client, then it may open up options for you (server based cron job, etc.). The comments above work but will still require you to "touch" their server. Unless you can (somehow), you're looking at external ways (above) that may/may not be reliable.

Comment: just found another solution, using Quartz.NET library for these purposes. lets see what get used thanks all!!